# Add stickers to imageview which is resizable and rotatable

Tags: android, image

I need to make an application where user is able to add custom stickers on image.
Rotate stickers
resize sticker

I read an article here:

[add snapchat like sticker features in your app: medium](https://blog.uptech.team/how-to-create-snapchat-like-stickers-for-android-50512957c351)

also i got the source code here:

[github link](https://github.com/uptechteam/MotionViews-Android)

i am able to use it and is exactly what i need
but i am not able to set the background of the image of sticker
it is always white and even if i add any custom sticker 
it is blurry

any one knows the solution kindly help

Comment: You can try Vector Drawable to avoid blurr image